# How to pass the Battle of Xin Ye

Tags: empire-defense-2

Are there any good strategies for this level, for beginners with minimum items and soldiers upgrades?

I have tried different paths and using the 4 given soldiers, i.e., spearman, archer, witch, and crossbow.

Answer (score 1):

Just use more SPEARMEN and WITCH, move the general when there are numbers in the top of the icon horse and you can easily go through the Xin Ye. And you can go to read **[this article](http://www.gameinformer.com/blogs/members/b/danyjerry_blog/archive/2014/06/24/td-tower-defense-beginner-guide-and-tips.aspx)** about the strategy of the game.